# Setting up Distributed testing with Jmeter using Azure VMs and behind firewall

Tags: azure, jmeter, performance-testing, windows-firewall

I am trying to set up distributed testing using `Jmeter 3.0`, the master and slave node are in Azure VMs(Windows 2012 R2 server) and are behind the firewall.

Error in starting  JMeter Server: 
I am checking the open ports in VM using netstat. When I use any of the ports which are listed as listening, in `server.rmi.localport` in JMeter property file(of server host) and start the JMeter server I am getting the below error:

> Server failed to start:java.rmi.server.ExportException:Port already in
>   use XXXX

The same issue is happening with all ports listed as listening using netstat.
I am trying to use a specific port for the server as the VM is behind a firewall and all ports are not open.